# examples of ie obj.attachEvent()

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

does anyone know how works the obj.attachEvent on ie?

I tried a few examples but they don't work. Also is this compatible with ie7?

What i tried is this :

```
var onload = function( ) {
        console.log("intercepting: " + this.status + " " + this.responseText);
    };

if($.browser.msie){
   console.log("it's IE...");
   this.attachEvent("load", onload);
}
```

All above inside an XMLHtppRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to assign that function to `xhrObject.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: yes Marcel, but i must set an attach so that captures the object event

Comment: @dyoser: Of which object? Again: what's `this` in your context?

Comment: it seems that chrome does not like this :(

Comment: @dyoser: does not like what? Do you get an error? Chrome supports XMLHttpRequests rather well.

Answer (score 3):

For `attachEvent`, you need to prefix the event name with `"on"`, e.g.

```
this.attachEvent("onload", onload);
```

This differs from the DOM Events' `addEventListener`, which requires the `"on"` to be omitted.

As Marcel pointed out, for XMLHttpRequests you need to bind to `onreadystatechange` instead, and check the `readyState` property inside the handler.  `onload` isn't supported for `XMLHttpRequest`.

On another note, you should avoid checking the browser and check feature support instead.  Internet Explorer 9 supports `addEventListener`, for instance:

```
var onreadystatechange = function( ) {
    if (this.readyState == 4)
        console.log("intercepting: " + this.status + " " + this.responseText);
};

if(!this.addEventListener && this.attachEvent){
   console.log("it's IE<9...");
   xhr.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", onreadystatechange);
}
else
    // use addEventListener
```

In reality though, you wouldn't use `attachEvent` or `addEventListener` on an XHR object; I doubt IE7 and lower will play nice with this, so you would just bind to the event property directly:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4)
        console.log("intercepting: " + this.status + " " + this.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Does IE's implementation of XHR support `onload` events?

Comment: i tried with the "onload", but it does not work. It seems that the xhr of ie does not implement this.

Comment: @Marcel: good spot, I didn't see that `this` was an XMLHttpRequest.  The answer still counts though, `"on"` is a required prefix for event names in `attachEvent` :-)

Comment: @dyoser: what doesn't attach well on IE8?  Which part of my answer are you referring to?

Comment: **Why** do you set the `onreadystatechange` handler using `attachEvent`? Can't you just use `xhr.onreadystatechange = …`? I'm feeling confused now, but it's getting hot here.

Comment: @Marcel: that's also a good point.  I'm bunged up with the flu here and it's really doing a number on me :-)  I guess I just focussed on answering the question without really thinking about what I'm doing.  Sorry about that :-)