# Can XHR trigger onreadystatechange multiple times with readyState=DONE?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

The [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-xhr-readystatechange) suggest following implementation:
Some simple code to do something with data from an XML document fetched over the network:

```
function processData(data) {
  // taking care of data
}

function handler() {
  if(this.readyState == this.DONE) {
    if(this.status == 200 &&
       this.responseXML != null &&
       this.responseXML.getElementById('test').textContent) {
      // success!
      processData(this.responseXML.getElementById('test').textContent);
      return;
    }
    // something went wrong
    processData(null);
  }
}

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = handler;
client.open("GET", "unicorn.xml");
client.send();
```

Is this implementation really correct?

During debug I found cases when the readystatechanged event handler is called more than once in a row with the same value of readyState == 4. I guess this behavior is correct, as specs says that each change of state must fire the event, and that readyState must always be equal to current state, so if several events pile up in the events queue, it's quite obvious, that one will get multiple calls with readyState == 4.

http://jsfiddle.net/44b3P/ -- this is the above example augmented with debugger call to pause execution just after the request is send, and with alert() in the processData. Once you unpause the execution you will get 3 alerts.

This example from w3c seems to be copy&pasted in multiple places in the web -- in particular OpenSocial seems to handle xhr events this way. Is it correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also saw the same behavior (DONE 200 being hit more than once, i.e. 2...n times) when debugging in Chrome Developer Tools.

To make it work always in debug mode as well, I found two options:

1. Use `onload` to verify the success of an XMLHTMLRequest [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-handlers)

   client.onload = handler;

   This version will not work in IE8. It must be a browser that implements the [XMLHttpRequestEventTarget](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#xmlhttprequesteventtarget) interface
2. Remove the `onreadystatechange` handler as soon as you have a `DONE 200` state.

   ```
   client.onreadystatechange = function() {
       // check if request is complete
       if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
           if (this.onreadystatechange) {
               client.onreadystatechange = null;
               handler();
           }
       }
   };
   ```

I have also opened an issue in [Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162837) for this problem, providing your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44b3P/) (Thanks!)

Comment: Just as an addendum - using the originally provided code, `this.onreadystatechange = null;` is sufficient, you don't need the original reference to the XHR (`client`).

Comment: It didn't work when I tried using `delete xhr.onreadystatechange`, changing it to `xhr.onreadystatechange = null` worked well.

Comment: to me this solution dint work, but the second answer in this solution worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728509/examples-of-ie-obj-attachevent

Comment: Which answer exactly? Their order might have changed since you wrote the above comment, @web_dev...

Answer (score 0):

I have never had my `onreadystatechange` handler executed multiple times with a `readyState` of 4.

I think assuming a single execution on DONE is correct.

Comment: Only one alert appears every time I reload the page, sorry. (latest Chrome)

Comment: The problem is ONLY in debug mode (I tested it only on Mac). You must open the Developer Tools and then reload the page. It is also not "deterministic" (for the user), since it sometimes (rarely) doesn't happen. I also could not understand the logic about how many times it is called.